# Populating an array of objects with a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through a number of items, and create an array. Each loop should be a new item in the array, but I'm having some issues doing it. It seems that only one set of items gets added, instead of multiple ones.

I've tried below code. Please help me to solve it.

```
function OpenPopup3(src,type,title){

 var myData = [];
 rows.each(function(index) {
     var temp_obj = {};
     temp_obj["src"] = $this.find('.elementOne').text(),
     temp_obj["type"] = $this.find('.elementTwo').text(),
     temp_obj["title"] = $this.find('.elementThree').text()
  myData.push(temp_obj);
 });

 $.magnificPopup.open({ 
    key: 'my-popup', 
    items: myData,
    type: 'inline',
    inline: { markup: '<div class=""><div class="mfp-close"></div>'+'<img class="mfp-src">'+'<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+'</div>' },
    gallery: { enabled: true }
 });
}
```

What I actually want is as below:

```
{
    src: "/googleimages/123/a.png",
    type: "Stuff",
    title: "Title1"
},
{
    src: "/googleimages/123/b.png",
    type: "Stuff",
    title: "Title2"
},
{
    src: "/googleimages/123/c.png",
    type: "Stuff",
    title: "Title3"
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use ; instead of , after $this.find('.elementTwo').text()

Comment: Where do you declare the rows variable that you're looping through? I believe that might only have one element in it.

Comment: What you want to do is creating an array of objects. This has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a **data format**, just like XML or CSV.

Comment: What is the issue with the code you have?

Comment: It is used to create popup gallery.

Comment: I don't know how to use that rows.each... i just copied code from net .. i am beginner in this.. can you help me in that? @MarcoDelValle 

If you have different code.. you can provide me i can change my function.. Hope you got that what i want.

Comment: @TahaShaikh you should provide the full example so people can help you out!

Answer (score 0):

First what does `rows` variable contain? it seems not declared anywhere.

Second you have syntax errors:

```
temp_obj["src"] = $(this).find('.elementOne').text();
temp_obj["type"] = $(this).find('.elementTwo').text();
temp_obj["title"] = $(this).find('.elementThree').text();
```

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the code. Overall this seems to be more like a  comment.